# AppCompatEditText tinting issue on lollipop and above

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I've just updated to appcompat-v7:22.1.0 and there seems to be a tinting issue with EditTexts where the colorControlActivated color is overlaying the colorControlNormal color.

Here is the source for an example app that demonstrates the issue: https://github.com/andrewgiang/EditTextIssue

### Lollipop tinting issue:

[image: tint issue on lollipop]

### Expected tint:

[image: 4.2 kitkat - expected image]